# Not Able to find Image File in Content Resolver

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I'm trying to upload image on server.

Following code is used to get the path of image.

```
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
    // DocumentProvider
    try {
        if (DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Content URI -> External : " + uri);
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];
                Log.e(TAG, "Type: " + type);
                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(type) + "/" + split[1];
                }

            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Content URI -> Downloads : " + uri);
                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
                Log.e(TAG, "Content uri: " + contentUri);

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];
                Log.e(TAG, "Type : " + type);
                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                        split[1]
                };
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Content URI -> Content : " + uri);
            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();
            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

private static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {column};

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        Log.e(TAG, "cursor.moveToFirst() : " + cursor.moveToFirst());
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Following code is used to call image intent.

```
public static Intent getPickImageChooserIntent(Context context) {
    List<Intent> allIntents = new ArrayList<>();
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    // collect all gallery intents
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    List<ResolveInfo> listGallery = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(galleryIntent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo res : listGallery) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(galleryIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(res.activityInfo.packageName);
        allIntents.add(intent);
    }

    // the main intent is the last in the  list (fucking android) so pickup the useless one
    Intent mainIntent = allIntents.get(allIntents.size() - 1);
    for (Intent intent : allIntents) {
        if (intent.getComponent() != null && DOCUMENT_APP_PATH.equalsIgnoreCase(intent.getComponent().getClassName())) {
            mainIntent = intent;
            break;
        }
    }
    allIntents.remove(mainIntent);

    // Create a chooser from the main  intent
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(mainIntent, context.getString(R.string.choose_image_text));
    // Add all other intents
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, allIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[allIntents.size()]));

    return chooserIntent;
}
```

I'm getting `cursor.moveToFirst()` as false.

File Choose from picker -

> content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A1000025026

Not Sure what i'm doing wrong. Is it the intent or content query?

Comment: `File Choose from picker -` ? If you mean that content scheme obtained from ACTION_GET_CONTENT, then why not just say so? Anything different only confuses.

Comment: `Following code is used to get the path of image.` From image? From that content scheme i think. From that nice uri. Dont try to get a path. Use the uri

Answer (score 0):

For image **capture** or selection from the **File Manager**, this code will work for you.

**Public** declare `params`

```
Uri filePath;
String mCurrentPhotoPath;
```

Alert to pick `camera` or `File Manager`

```
public void chooseImage() {
        final CharSequence[] optionsMenu = {"Camera", "Choose from File Manager", "Cancel"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BusinessImagesActivity.this);
        builder.setItems(optionsMenu, (dialogInterface, i) -> {
            if (optionsMenu[i].equals("Camera")) {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            } else if (optionsMenu[i].equals("Choose from File Manager")) {
                Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                fileManagerResultLauncher.launch(pickPhoto);
            } else if (optionsMenu[i].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
```

For **camera**:

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                filePath = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.example.packagename.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, filePath);
                cameraResultLauncher.launch(takePictureIntent);
            }
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

**Activity Launcher:**

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> cameraResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
                    filePath = Uri.fromFile(f);
                    //filePath pass to function uploading image to server
                    uploadImage(filePath);
                }
            });
```

For `File Manager` **Activity Launcher**:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> fileManagerResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Intent data = result.getData();
                    if (data != null) {
                        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                        filePath = selectedImage;
                        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                        if (selectedImage != null) {
                            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                            if (cursor != null) {
                                cursor.moveToFirst();
                                cursor.close();
                                uploadImage(filePath);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

**Permissions needed:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Comment: So, i'm trying to pick image not only from gallery but also from Files Manager where videos and audios are also picked.

Comment: try the code I updated for you